# setting up SpigotMC causes crash and asks for Git details?

Tags: java, git

I know this is probably the wrong place to ask this question but seeing that I want to develop plugins with this I thought I might ask here. When running the latest BuildTools.jar to set up a 1.8.8 SpigotMC server, it runs fine for a while until it suddenly says it requires git login details.
Here is what the command line says at that point:

```
Checking out files:  96% (731/761)
Checking out files:  97% (739/761)
Checking out files:  98% (746/761)
Checking out files:  99% (754/761)
Checking out files: 100% (761/761)
Checking out files: 100% (761/761), done.
Resetting Spigot-API to Bukkit...
fatal: No such remote: upstream
HEAD is now at 01d18206 Add non-mutative getCrossProduct method to Vector.
  Applying patches to Spigot-API...

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <gjoncaadrian@gmail.com>) not allowed

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <gjoncaadrian@gmail.com>) not allowed
  Something did not apply cleanly to Spigot-API.
  Please review above details and finish the apply then
  save the changes with rebuildPatches.sh
Error compiling Spigot. Please check the wiki for FAQs.
If this does not resolve your issue then please pastebin the entire BuildTools.log.txt file when seeking support.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running command, return status !=0: [C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe, applyPatches.sh]
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess0(Builder.java:805)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess(Builder.java:742)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.main(Builder.java:607)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:40)
```

If someone knows how to fix this it would help tons.

Comment: 1. (Hi &welcome) Install/ensure installed git for your OS!

Comment: 2. (Decide which user name/email to use...then) Execute `git config` as proposed by command line output/answer. 3. Re-run "buildtools"...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you execute the config commands matter. Make sure you use double quotes.

```
git config --global user.email "gjoncaadrian@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "yourname"
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! You have just saved me a morning of peril.

Comment: Glad to hear man :)

Comment: No luck for me :/